# URL regex: required protocol and optional www

Tags: regex

Should pass:

```
http://google.com
http://google.com/
http://www.google.com
```

(and same with https)

Should not pass:

```
http://www.google
www.google.com
```

This one seems to be close:

```
^(((http(?:s)?\:\/\/)|www\.)[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}(?:\/?|(?:\/[\w\-]+)*)(?:\/?|\/\w+((\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})?)(?:\?[\w]+\=[\w\-]+)?)?(?:\&[\w]+\=[\w\-]+)*)$
```

, but it passes:

```
http://www.go
www.google.com
```

Comment: This regex is horrible. What programming language do you use? Most certainly, there are functions for this **exact** purpose included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var reg = /^http(s)?:\/{2}(w{3}\.)?(\w+)\.com(\/)?$/;

var domains = ['http://google.com', 'https://www.google.com', 'google.com'];

domains.forEach(function (domain) {
  console.log(reg.test(domain))
});
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

```
(?:https?:\/\/)(?:www.)?.+\.com\/?
```

See at work: http://regexr.com/3egdt.

**Break down:**

```
(?:https?:\/\/)  starts with 'http' (or https) ':\\'
(?:www.)?        domain may start with 'www.'
.+               domain name (whatever you want)
\.com            ends with '.com'
\/?              may contain '\' after
```

Comment: Could be simplified if using another delimiter (like `~`): https://regex101.com/r/y8A0Ic/1